# Weird change in CPU usage makes RubyMine almost unusable [Graph included]

Tags: performance, rubymine

I have been using RubyMine for about 2 months now and been experiencing performance issues ever since. I thought it was because of the buggy debugger, then because of swapping.. Nay

So I realized that for 5 - 10 minutes it works fine, until RubyMine (or Ubuntu?) decides to use alternatively one core at 100 % and the other not so much. It sometimes goes back to normal but tipically stays the same, makin it really unpleasant to use.

So here you see the change around 30 sec.

What do you think?
[image: clear change in cpu usage at 30 secs]

Comment: If you haven't yet determined whether it's RubyMine or the OS (Ubuntu) that is eating up your CPU, I don't think you've done enough analysis to ask the right question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Providing a CPU snapshot](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1144) for RubyMine may help to identify the problem if it's RubyMine process eating your resources.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late to the party but apparently this problem still pops up now and again :)

i had a similar situation where rubymine would take up all available CPU in all cores and would just freeze. initially it was installed via snap but when i uninstalled it used the rubymine.sh i got the same issue.

deleting the cache directory under /home/user/.cache/JetBrains/RubyMine2023.3 did the trick for me :)